# I get a uncaught type error cannot read property length of undefined when trying to fetch a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to include notifications in my rails app and I am following this tutorial to the letter https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications

Everything goes well up to the point where I try to fetch the notifications div with Javascript where I am supposed to append notifications from a JSON Endpoint. But somehow I can't fetch the div so the whole following logic fails.

If you need more code I am happy to share my github repo. Would really appreciate some help :)

**_navbar.html.erb**

```
<div class="navbar-listy-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<% if current_user.is_a?(User) %>
  <!-- Avatar with dropdown menu -->
    <div class="btn-group dropleft" data-behavior="notifications">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" data-behavior="notifications-link">
        <i class="far fa-bell icon-selector"></i><span data-behavior="unread-count"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" data-behavior="notification-items">

      </div>
    </div>
```

**notifications.js.coffee**

```
class Notifications
constructor: ->
@notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
@setup() if @notifications.length > 0


setup: ->
console.log(@notifications)
$("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick
$.ajax(
  url: "/notifications.json"
  dataType: "JSON"
  method: "GET"
  success: @handleSuccess
)

handleClick: (e) =>
$.ajax(
  url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
  dataType: "JSON"
  method: "POST"
  success: ->
    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(0)
)

handleSuccess: (data) =>
if data.length > 0
  items = $.map data, (notification) ->
    "<a class= 'dropdown-item' href='#{notification.url}'> # . 
{notification.actor} #{notification.action} 
{notification.notifiable.type}</a>"
    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)
    $("[data-behavior = 'notification-items']").html(items)

else
    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)
    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html("<p>No new notifications</p>")

   jQuery ->
   new Notifications
```

**EDIT**

My initial question is that that even the first step of the code (i.e fetching a div @notifications with jquery fails). However, I know that the page loads because if I put an alert message it executes on page load.

**notifications.js.coffee**

```
class Notifications
constructor: ->
 @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
 @setup()



setup: ->
 console.log(@notifications)



jQuery ->
new Notifications
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleSuccess` you have the two branches of the if-else:

```
if data.length > 0
  items = ...
else
  $(...).text(items.length)
```

In other words, when `data.length` is greater than zero, you're referencing the `length` of an undefined variable `items`, causing the error you're seeing.

For future questions, please see instructions on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you should include the relevant bits of the error message in your question.

Comment: Thanks !! That's indeed an error. I could just delete the first line after the else statement right? But my initial question is a bit different. My problem is that I don't even get the @notifications when I try to console.log it , so the whole code doesn't work.. I feel like it has something to do with the use of coffeescript .. So for example this doesn't work class Notifications
         constructor: ->
          @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
          @setup()
          setup: ->
          console.log(@notifications)

   jQuery ->
    new Notifications`

Comment: Could you please clarify your original question, as I don't see what the "initial question" is if not the question about the error you mentioned. You say the "logic fails", but what does that mean? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Also comments are not really good for extended code. Editing your original question is the preferred method to add more context.

Comment: Sorry not really an expert in SO yet :) I just edited the question